# Where are the scheduled tasks in the new ECS 'experience' (Jan 2023)?

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS has a new interface for ECS. The scheduled tasks tab is not there anymore. Does anyone have idea where they went (without searching for that in the top bar)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's available in the new console yet. You can use the toggle in the top left to go to the "classic" console and edit scheduled tasks there.